# python3で2次元配列を、グルーピングしたJSONに変換する方法ってありますか？

Tags: python, python3, json, highcharts

pythonで以下のような2次元配列を

```
[
  ['部署A','ID100',10],
  ['部署A','ID101',11],
  ['部署B','ID200',8],
  ['部署B','ID201',30],
]
```

以下のようなJSONに変換する方法はありますでしょうか。。（部署ごとにグループして、ID分配列にしたいです）

```
[
  {
   department:'部署A',
   data:[
     {ID:'ID100',value:10},
     {ID:'ID101',value:11}
   ]
  },
  {
   department:'部署B',
   data:[
     {ID:'ID200',value:8},
     {ID:'ID201',value:30}
   ]
  }
]
```

実現したいこととして、以下のHighChartsグラフを作成するためのデータを作りたいです。
良い方法はありますでしょうか。
https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.highcharts.com%2Fsamples%2Fcodepen%2Fhighcharts%2Fdemo%2Fpacked-bubble-split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下は [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) で部署毎にグルーピングしておいて、`json.dumps()` で JSON 形式に変換する方法です。

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import json

tbl = [
  ['部署A', 'ID100', 10],
  ['部署A', 'ID101', 11],
  ['部署B', 'ID200',  8],
  ['部署B', 'ID201', 30],
]

lst = [{
        'department': dep,
        'data': [{'ID': d[1], 'value': d[2]} for d in data]
       } for dep, data in groupby(tbl, key=itemgetter(0))]

json_text = json.dumps(lst, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
print(json_text)
=>
[
  {
    "department": "部署A",
    "data": [
      {
        "ID": "ID100",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "ID": "ID101",
        "value": 11
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "department": "部署B",
    "data": [
      {
        "ID": "ID200",
        "value": 8
      },
      {
        "ID": "ID201",
        "value": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: 有難うございます！！まさにこの様なコードが知りたかったです。
ベストアンサーのチェックを入れました！